# Do I have to send my passport to Travisa?

Tags: visas, cuba

I will be travelling to Cuba from the US (US citizen) this January. Travisa is a visa company that I want to use for getting an educational visa to Cuba because the Cuban consulate will NOT answer the phone and I am in the US, far from Washington DC. Travisa wants me to send them my passport. Is this normal? Just checking!

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Travisa is the visa service you have chosen to use. They require your passport so they can deliver it to the consulate, the consulate can use it to process your application, and so they can deliver it back to you. They won't be able to do the job without your passport.

I, of course, cannot promise that nothing will go wrong, but Travisa is a recommended service provider by the likes of [Stanford University](https://web.stanford.edu/group/fms/fingate/staff/travel/res_jobaid/passport_visa.html), [Dartmouth](http://global.dartmouth.edu/travel-resources/passport-and-visa-services), and [the Government of India](http://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-dyn/content/article/2008/05/04/AR2008050401419.html).